# Multiple warnings nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I often start nautilus from the terminal, e.g.

`nautilus . &`

I get the following warnings:

```
(nautilus:11016): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
<IntrospectionModule 'Nautilus' from '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Nautilus-3.0.typelib'>
Insync Nautilus Plugin
<class 'insync_plugin.InsyncExtension'>
('[__init__ insync plugin]', <insync_plugin.InsyncExtension object at 0x7fb308127780 (uninitialized at 0x(nil))>)
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Nautilus works as expected, but all these warnings are quite annoying. From what I see, there are three different things going on here:

- GTK-Warning about some client
- Some python module (maybe Insync? - A google drive integration) does not specify some version
- Nautilus cannot finde network shares, since I dont have any (?)

I already googled and found a couple of answers to related problems where nautilus would either not work at all or not work with `gksu`. But since nautilus works fine for me, I did not find any solution so far. Anyone an idea how to get rid off all (or maybe at least one or two) messages?

Comment: I don't know what these warnings exactly mean or by what they might be caused. However, you can also open the current directory from a terminal in your system's default file manager (which should be Nautilus) using `xdg-open .` instead. That will automatically send the process to the background and disown it from the terminal window, so that you can also close the terminal later while keeping the Nautilus window open. Does that command produce less errors/warnings, or exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `xdg-open` gives me the same warning messages. However, I noticed that I only get these messages once during a terminal session. So, if I open multiple nautilus instances from the same terminal, I only get these warnings once (the first time)